# Sobre HTTPS no Meta

Tags: bug, suporte, status-futuro

A extensão [HTTPS Everywhere](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/https-everywhere/gcbommkclmclpchllfjekcdonpmejbdp) do Chrome serve pra forçar a criptografia. Ela funciona no Stack mas dá um alerta no Meta:

### Stack:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Meta:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso é proposital?

Comment: Acho que não é proposital, já que o site principal está ok. Provavelmente falou algum mapeamento no servidor web.

Comment: We fully intend to get there, but we have some non-trivial work to do before SSL can be enables on meta sites. Here is some background: http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/

Comment: @Oded Thank you for the information.

Comment: De nada @Andrey :)